# Clientarea of Windows MFC SDI application frozen after returning from STRG-ALT-ENTF

Tags: mfc, direct2d, sdi

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I have created an MFC SDI Application with Direct2D for drawing. 
So I am listening to

```
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_DRAW2D, &CIGUIDEView::OnDraw2d)
```

messages for painting into the client area of the application. It all works fine, until I hit STRG-ALT-ENTF and return from the windows lock screen. Then the client area gets 'frozen', i.e. it is not refreshing. The application itself however is still responsive. When I set a breakpoint in

`OnDraw2d(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){..}`

Visual Studio breaks, so it is evident that all the drawing actually should happen. However, the application looks like this:

[No graphics update in client area of MFC SDI application using Direct2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhBk.png)

Funny enough, this does ONLY happen when the mouse pointer is inside the client area while I hit STRG-ALT-ENTF. If it is outside, there is no problem.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: You are *probably* failing to [handle device loss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/drawing-with-direct2d#handling-device-loss). Without a [mcve], you can't expect anything more substantial than a guess. Please read [ask].

Comment: I read that MFC Direct2D wrapper classes take care of device loss. Anyhow, I will try to deliver a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Failing to deliver a minimal reproducible example, I found out the cause: In the aforementioned drawing operation, I used a CD2DPathGeometry object that got invalid. So it was after all due to device loss as you had mentioned. The solution is to catch the event of D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET as an HRESULT of m_renderTarget.EndDraw(); and recreate the objects that have become invalid manually.